# Add a spinner in a widget

Tags: android, spinner, android-appwidget

I am trying to set a spinner inside a widget. The xml file with the widget layout is showing all the items well. But when I try to try the layout on my phone I get "There was a problem with the widget" and I don't know how to fix it.

Another question, I want to get access to the spinner and set the event, I know I have to use remoteViews, but I don't know anything more.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a spinner to your widget.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) for the permitted View types you can use to build your widget.